# Why wont this program display the text?

Tags: java, swing

There are some other problems that have arisen but the program when it ran had a lot of errors and no outputs. one was a null pointer. now it also says "The type Talk must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)". and it says also "void is an invalid type for the variable actionPerformed".

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Talk extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JTextField first;
    JTextField second;
    JButton b = new JButton("ok");
    public Talk(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,10,20));
        panel.add(new JLabel("First Name"));
        JTextField first = new JTextField(8);
        panel.add(first);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Last Name"));
        JTextField last = new JTextField(8);
        panel.add(last);
        panel.add(b);
        b.addActionListener(this);





public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource()==b){
        String data = first.getText();
        String data2 = second.getText();
        System.out.println("Welcome " + data + data2);
    }

}}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Talk frame = new Talk();
    frame.setTitle("Your Name");
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}}
```

Comment: Method inside constructor? Buddy first read a good book of java's basic concepts.

Answer (score 2):

1. You've tried to declare a method within a method
2. You've tried to declare a method outside of the class...

The two are related...

```
    public Talk() { // Start of constructor
        //...still in method
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == b) {
            String data = first.getText();
            String data2 = second.getText();
            System.out.println("Welcome " + data + data2);
        }

    }
} // end of constructor
```

Take the `actionPerformed` method and move it outside of the constructor...

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Talk extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JTextField first;
    JTextField second;
    JButton b = new JButton("ok");

    public Talk() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 20));
        panel.add(new JLabel("First Name"));
        JTextField first = new JTextField(8);
        panel.add(first);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Last Name"));
        JTextField last = new JTextField(8);
        panel.add(last);
        panel.add(b);
        b.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == b) {
            String data = first.getText();
            String data2 = second.getText();
            System.out.println("Welcome " + data + data2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Talk frame = new Talk();
        frame.setTitle("Your Name");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Updated**

You will also get a `NullPointerException` because the you are shadowing your variables...

```
// You declare these instance variables here...
JTextField first;
JTextField second;
JButton b = new JButton("ok");

public Talk() {
    But re-declare them here (as local variables)...
    //...
    JTextField first = new JTextField(8);
    //...
    JTextField last = new JTextField(8);
```

This means that when the `actionPerformed` method is called `first` (and `second`) are still `null`.

Remove the local re-declaration...

```
public Talk() {
    //...
    first = new JTextField(8);
    //...
    last = new JTextField(8);
```

Comment: This is not the solution. you should write it in comment.

Comment: @DeepakTiwari It is now...answers aren't always solutions ;)

Comment: @user3443390 Where?  Did you try using the full example I added (it will still give you a `NullPointerException` if you run it, but it will at least run)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

you are getting the `null pointer exception` because you are not using the class variable which you declared(Using local variables instead).

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Talk extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JTextField first;
    JTextField second;
    JTextField result;
    JLabel res=new JLabel("result");
    JButton b = new JButton("ok");
    public Talk(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,10,20));
        panel.add(new JLabel("First Name"));
        first = new JTextField(8);
        panel.add(first);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Last Name"));
        second = new JTextField(8);
        panel.add(second);
        panel.add(b);
        b.addActionListener(this);

        panel.add(res);
        result = new JTextField(8);
        panel.add(result);


    }


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource()==b){
        String data = first.getText();
        String data2 = second.getText();
        result.setText("Welcome " + data +" "+data2);
        //System.out.println("Welcome " + data + data2);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Talk frame = new Talk();
    frame.setTitle("Your Name");
    frame.setSize(700,700);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: ok this works but how do I get it to paste it into a program instead of print it

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution.. you had declared variable first and second at class level but have not used them

```
 import javax.swing.*;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class Talk extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
        JTextField first;
        JTextField second;
        JButton b = new JButton("ok");
        public Talk(){
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            add(panel);
            panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,10,20));
            panel.add(new JLabel("First Name"));
            first = new JTextField(8);
            panel.add(first);
            panel.add(new JLabel("Last Name"));
             second = new JTextField(8);
            panel.add(second);
            panel.add(b);
            b.addActionListener(this);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Talk frame = new Talk();
        frame.setTitle("Your Name");
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("in actionPerformed1");
        if (arg0.getSource()==b){
            String data = first.getText();
            String data2 = second.getText();
            System.out.println("Welcome " + data + data2);
        }

    }}
```

Comment: why is it telling me to remove the override annotation

Comment: You can remove that there is no harm in it and this above program is working fine..